# MPAndroidChart Simultaneous Multiple Chart Zooming

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have three line charts vertically aligned in 3 different fragments. Is there a way for me to zoom in on one chart and have the same zoom x and y axis zoom amount be reflected on the two other charts?

Is there some example code I can reference?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521004/mpandroidchart-have-one-graph-mirror-the-zoom-swipes-on-a-sister-graph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPAndroidChart: Have one graph mirror the zoom/swipes on a sister graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521004/mpandroidchart-have-one-graph-mirror-the-zoom-swipes-on-a-sister-graph)

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart). And especially focus on the `OnChartGestureListener`. It delivers callbacks when a chart is manipulated (e.g. scaled) and allows to react to it.