# Sync scale & translation of 2 charts in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I have multiple LineCharts in a RecyclerView. When the user zooms or pans one chart, I would like the others to update to the same zoom / pan setting. I looked at ViewPortHandler and OnChartGestureListener but the solution wasn't obvious to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`OnChartGestureListener` is the way to go.

Just update the scale / zoom / translate state of the other charts according to the values returned from the listener.

More on that [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport).

Comment: Detailed answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592929/11980977